# Python parallel threads

Tags: python, multithreading

Here the code which download 3 files, and do something with it.
But before starting Thread2 it waits until Thread1 will be finished. How make them run together?
Specify some examples with commentary. Thanks

```
import threading
import urllib.request


def testForThread1():
    print('[Thread1]::Started')
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen('http://192.168.85.16/SOME_FILE')
    data = resp.read()
    # Do something with it
    return 'ok'


def testForThread2():
    print('[Thread2]::Started')
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen('http://192.168.85.10/SOME_FILE')
    data = resp.read()
    # Do something with it
    return 'ok'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = threading.Thread(name="Hello1", target=testForThread1())
    t1.start()
    t2 = threading.Thread(name="Hello2", target=testForThread2())
    t2.start()
    print(threading.enumerate())
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
    exit(0)
```

Comment: You're executing the thread-target function in the thread assignment. Effectively, you are executing `threading.Thread(name='Hello1', target='ok')`. Try `t1 = threading.Thread(name="Hello1", target=testForThread1)` instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are executing the target function for the thread in the thread instance creation.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = threading.Thread(name="Hello1", target=testForThread1()) # <<-- here
    t1.start()
```

This is equivalent to:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = testForThread1() # == 'ok', this is the blocking execution
    t1 = threading.Thread(name="Hello1", target=result) 
    t1.start()
```

It's `Thread.start()`'s job to execute that function and store its result somewhere for you to reclaim. As you can see, the previous format was executing the blocking function in the main thread, preventing you from being able to parallelize (e.g. it would have to finish that function execution before getting to the line where it calls the second function).

The proper way to set the thread in a non-blocking fashion would be:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = threading.Thread(name="Hello1", target=testForThread1) # tell thread what the target function is
    # notice no function call braces for the function "testForThread1"
    t1.start() # tell the thread to execute the target function
```

Answer (score 3):

For this, we can use **threading** but it's not efficient since you want to download files. so the total time will be equal to the sum of download time of all files.
If you have good internet speed, then **multiprocessing** is the best way.

```
import multiprocessing


def test_function():
    for i in range(199999998):
        pass
    
    
t1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=test_function)
t2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=test_function)
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

This is the fastest solution. You can check this using following command:

```
time python3 filename.py
```

you will get the following output like this:

```
real    0m6.183s
user    0m12.277s
sys     0m0.009s
```

here, **real = user + sys**

**user time** is the time taken by python file to execute.
but you can see that above formula doesn't satisfy because each function takes **approx 6.14**. But due to multiprocessing, both take **6.18 seconds** and reduced total time by **multiprocessing in parallel.**

You can get more about it from [here](https://www.quantstart.com/articles/Parallelising-Python-with-Threading-and-Multiprocessing).

Comment: In Python (and to be more specific, the CPython implementation), multiprocessing is usually the way to go if CPU is the bottleneck (as is the case with your `test_function()`). But if the work is IO-bound, threads can do just fine (even better, in fact, as they are more-lightweight).